# Splitting and Joining Machines

Tags: haskell

A small program I use as my "hello world" of streaming libraries is the following:

- For each line of `stdin`
- Interpret the line as a file-name
- If the file represented by the file-name has changed
- ... (including the possibility of being removed or added)
- ... Then output the file-name

This works well because you can draw a nice data-flow diagram that should convert easily to pipe-like libraries because of the data-plumbing style algorithm...

However, I usually have some issues with this seemingly straight-forward exercise when it comes to splitting and re-joining a stream of values.

The "Machines" library by Edward Kmett has been the cleanest implementation I've made so-far, but is no exception to me encountering implementation issues (hopefully just due to my misunderstandings).

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/sordina/f3fb3cec2d76376d57c3)

I've linked to my solution as a gist as well as appended to the end of this question as a code-block and welcome all code reviews, but I would especially like help with the following:

- Identifying existing functionality in the 'machines' libraries that I can remove from my implementation.
- Finding an exiting replacement or improvement for my splitZipWith function
- Removing the IO dependency from as many of my machines as possible

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module UniqHash (main, uniqHash) where

import Data.Machine
import Control.Monad          (when)
import System.Directory       (doesFileExist)
import Control.Category       (Category)
import Data.Digest.Pure.MD5   (MD5Digest, hash')
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

import qualified Data.Map        as M
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

--- UniqHash

main :: IO ()
main = runT_ $ stdinMachine ~> uniqHash ~> stdoutMachine

uniqHash :: ProcessT IO String String
uniqHash = splitZip echo (fileExists ~> md5machine)
        ~> construct (lookupM M.empty)

--- Helpers

stdinMachine :: SourceT IO String
stdinMachine = construct $ liftIO getContents >>= mapM_ yield . lines

stdoutMachine :: ProcessT IO String ()
stdoutMachine = repeatedly $ await >>= liftIO . putStrLn

fileExists :: ProcessT IO String (Maybe String)
fileExists = repeatedly $ do
  fn <- await
  ex <- liftIO $ doesFileExist fn

  yield $ if ex then Just fn
                else Nothing

md5machine :: ProcessT IO (Maybe String) (Maybe MD5Digest)
md5machine = repeatedly $ await >>= liftIO . fileMD5 >>= yield
  where
  fileMD5 :: Maybe String -> IO (Maybe MD5Digest)
  fileMD5 (Just fileName) = fmap (Just . hash') (B.readFile fileName)
  fileMD5  Nothing        = return Nothing

lookupM :: (Category k, Ord o, Eq a) => M.Map o a -> PlanT (k (o, a)) o m ()
lookupM m = do
  (fileName, hashVal) <- await

  case M.lookup fileName m of
       Nothing -> yield fileName
       Just v  -> when (hashVal /= v) (yield fileName)

  lookupM (M.insert fileName hashVal m)

-- Possibly exist in libraries?

double :: MachineT IO (Is o) o
double = repeatedly $ do
  i <- await
  yield i
  yield i

splitZipWith :: ProcessT IO a a' -> ProcessT IO a b' -> TeeT IO a' b' c -> MachineT IO (Is a) c
splitZipWith a b o = double ~> fit cappedT (tee a b o)
  where
  -- Redefined since this is private...
  cappedT :: T a a b -> Is a b
  cappedT R = Refl
  cappedT L = Refl

splitZip :: ProcessT IO a a' -> ProcessT IO a b' -> MachineT IO (Is a) (a', b')
splitZip a b = splitZipWith a b tpair

tpair :: MachineT IO (T t t1) (t, t1)
tpair = repeatedly $ do
  fn <- awaits L
  md <- awaits R
  yield (fn,md)
```

Comment: It looks like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-machines-0.2.3.1/docs/Data-Machine-Concurrent.html should be able to solve this problem. Trying now.

Comment: It has been 3.5 years now. Do you want to review your own old code?